# Does Eclipse Deeplearning4j provide a JAR file download?

Tags: deeplearning4j, nd4j

This question comes up a lot on the support channel. People think downloading JAR files would simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Deeplearning4j only supports developing using a build tool such as Maven.

https://deeplearning4j.org/buildtools

(It is possible to download JAR files from the Maven repository, but there are literally hundreds of deps.)

Answer (score 0):

One trick that I sometimes use for quick samples or tests is to add SKIL's classpath to javac/java like so:

`javac -cp "/opt/skil/lib/*" Dl4jTest.java`

Then just include `.` and either `/opt/skil/native/*` or `/opt/skil/cuda/*` when you run it.

`java -cp "/opt/skil/lib/*:/opt/skil/cuda/*:." Dl4jTest`